# Eclipse CDT: 'can't find a source file' while debugging

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, unicode, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse with CDT for C++ development. However, I'm forced to use ASCII-symbols in paths to my source files to succesfully debug my programs. When source files are located in folders with non-English characters in their names, Eclipse gives an error:

> Can't find a source file at
>   "/home/\321\202\320\265\321\201\321\202/1.cpp"  Locate the file or
>   edit the source lookup path to include its location.

Is there any option that enables Eclipse to do proper Unicode processing?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps move your code to a workspace that sits at root, as in /workspace/projectName/src/1.cpp

If you can't find out exactly why and solve it, the next best thing is to circumvent...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/57027/

I had the same problem and this solution worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! I don't use Eclipse CDT anymore, so I hope someone will have a chance to check this solution and comment on it here)

Comment: You should explain what the link you pointed to is describing, not just add the link.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question. For me it was some weird behaviour in eclipse therefore starting eclipse like:

```
./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState -refresh
```

removed the issue for me